# How exactly works the Angular *ngFor in this example?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am pretty new in Angular 2 and I am not so into JavaScript\TypeScript (I came from Java) and I have some doubt about an example that I am studying related how to a component can use a property defined in another component (property\event binding). The example show how an array of element declared in a child component can be used and shown in the parent component.

So I have the **app-component** that is the **parent component**.

This is the **app-component** "view" named **app-component.html**:

```
<div class="container">
  <app-cockpit></app-cockpit>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <app-server-element
        *ngFor="let serverElement of serverElements"
        [element]="serverElement"></app-server-element>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

From what I can undestand this code generate **app-server-element** (another component of my application with its layout) starting from the **serverElements** array that is defined into the **app.component.ts** class, this one:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  serverElements = [{type: 'server', name: 'TestServer', content: 'Just a Test'}];
}
```

So here I have a this first doubt: doing:

```
<app-server-element
    *ngFor="let serverElement of serverElements"
    [element]="serverElement">
</app-server-element>
```

The ***ngFor** directive is iterating on the **serverElements** array that is defined into the **app.component.ts** class (related to the main **app-component** component) and not on the **server-element.component.ts**  class (related to the  component).

It works fine but it seems to me a little strange. Why? My idea is that this ***ngFor** directive is declared into the HTML code of the **app-component.html** related to the , so the iteration is on an array that is defined in the related class.

Is it or am I missing something?

Comment: The loop belongs to parent component (app-conmponent), and it renders N number of child components (server-whatever), passing a prop `element` === each element of the array from parent component. The view belongs to parent component, so it can use data only from parent script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In angular, when you write a directive preceded by an aserisk that is actually syntactic sugar for a more complex structure. For `*ngFor`, the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#inside-ngfor) gives this example:

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes; let i=index; let odd=odd; trackBy: trackById" [class.odd]="odd">
  ({{i}}) {{hero.name}}
</div>
```

The `*ngFor` is first rewritten to a `template` attribute:

```
<div template="ngFor let hero of heroes; let i=index; let odd=odd; trackBy: trackById" [class.odd]="odd">
  ({{i}}) {{hero.name}}
</div>
```

Then the `template` attribute is extracted out to an `ng-template` directive wrapping the element that contained the original `*ngFor`.

```
<ng-template ngFor let-hero [ngForOf]="heroes" let-i="index" let-odd="odd" [ngForTrackBy]="trackById">
  <div [class.odd]="odd">({{i}}) {{hero.name}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

The same rewriting happens with your code:

```
<app-server-element
    *ngFor="let serverElement of serverElements"
    [element]="serverElement">
</app-server-element>
```

is actually just a shorthand for:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-serverElement [ngForOf]="serverElements">
    <app-server-element [element]="serverElement"></app-server-element>
</ng-template>
```

From the expanded form of the `ngFor` it should now be obvious that `serverElements` is referenced entirely outside the `app-server-element` component.

Comment: Ok, your answer clarifies any doubt