# Display array in the DOM

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm sorry for my little knowledge in Angular. I'm learning it :)

I Would like to display in the template an array field. And it doesn't work in the way I'm doing it. :(

Home.page.TS

```
appInfo: any[] = [
    {
      title: 'Chapitre 1',
      description: 'Contenu'
    }
  ];
```

home.page.html

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Application de Test
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content >
  <h1>{{appInfo.title}}</h1>
  <ion-text>{{appInfo.description}}</ion-text>

</ion-content>
```

It doesn't show the filed.

Comment: You need to loop it with `*ngFor` like  `<ion-content *ngFor= "let data of appInfo" 
  <h1>{{data.title}}</h1>
  <ion-text>{{data.description}}</ion-text>

</ion-content>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How exactly works the Angular \*ngFor in this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44521677/how-exactly-works-the-angular-ngfor-in-this-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ngFor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) to iterate over arrays:

```
<ion-content *ngFor="let info of appInfo">
  <h1>{{info.title}}</h1>
  <ion-text>{{info.description}}</ion-text>
</ion-content>
```

If you want to display just the first item:

```
<ion-content *ngIf="appInfo && appInfo.length > 0">
  <h1>{{appInfo[0].title}}</h1>
  <ion-text>{{appInfo[0].description}}</ion-text>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: *ngFor is the only way ?

Comment: Thanks so much. I was looking for the solution with first item :)

Comment: Can i ask you on more question ? What about if i want to show the second Item ?

Comment: Then do something like `<ion-content *ngIf="appInfo && appInfo.length > 1">
  <h1>{{appInfo[1].title}}</h1>...`. However, `ngFor` is your friend. You can also use `index`: `*ngFor="let info of appInfo; let index"`.

Comment: Thanks so so much. pzaenger

Comment: You are welcome. Just take a look at the [API](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf): everything you need is there.

Answer (score 0):

Use *ngFor structural directive

```
<ion-header>
 <ion-toolbar>
   <ion-title>
    Application de Test
  </ion-title>
 </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content *ngFor="let infor of appInfo">
 <h1>{{infor.title}}</h1>
 <ion-text>{{infor.description}}</ion-text>
</ion-content>
```

Another long way to get array data is given.

```
    heroes = ['Windstorm', 'Bombasto', 'Magneta', 'Tornado'];
    myHero1 = this.heroes[0];
    myHero2 = this.heroes[1];
    myHero3 = this.heroes[2];
    myHero4 = this.heroes[3];
```

.html file

```
    <p [innerText]="myHero1"></p>
    <p [innerText]="myHero2"></p>
    <p>{{myHero3}}</p>
    <p>{{myHero4}}</p>
```

Comment: Your second approach looks interesting too, and useful in some context. Thanks a lot. I will keep this in mind too :)