# Why are built-in attribute directives surrounded by square brackets?

Tags: angular

Why do we need to use square brackets for built-in Angular directives, like ngClass, ngStyle?

Example:

```
<some-element [ngClass]="'first second'">...</some-element>
```

Why not using like code below?

```
<some-element ngClass="'first second'">...</some-element>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All built-in directives, regardless of attribute or structural are denoted by enclosing square brackets. `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` are syntactical sugar (or [shorthand syntax](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#shorthand-syntax)) for [`[ngForOf]`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts#L123) and [`[ngIf]`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_if.ts#L151). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44523841/6513921).

Why the square braces? Because the in-built directives have the data bound to them using [`@Input`](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#pass-values-into-the-directive-with-an-input-data-binding) decorator (examples: [`ngIf`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_if.ts#L166) and [`ngClass`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_class.ts#L60)). And as known before [data are bound](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#binding-to-an-input-property) to `@Input` property using square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35944965/4786620) on template syntax.
Also you will retrieve more details in [Angular official docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax)

With your example, you could simply do :

```html
<some-element class="first second">...</some-element>
```

Because in this example, you don't use the features of `ngClass` directive. Just set regular `class` via html attribute in this case.

But to invoke an Angular directive you should use square braces. 
Then in this case :

```html
<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': isFirst, 'second': isSecond}"></someElement>
```

`NgClass` directive will add `first` class name to `some-element` if local property `isFirst` is `true`, and same thing for `second`.

Each directive has a `selector` to be invoked by Angular template compiler.
In the case of `NgClass`, the selector is `[ngClass]`.

Excerpt of source code :

```js
@Directive({selector: '[ngClass]'})
export class NgClass implements DoCheck  {
...
```

Check for more details these resources :
  - [Angular directives](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives)
  - [Angular code for NgClass](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_class.ts)